# Classify finitely-generated modules over $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$ up to isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finite-fields

While studying the classification of finitely-generated modules over PIDs, I came across this exercise: Classify finitely-generated modules over $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$ up to isomorphism. It would be nice to have a solution as an example to illustrate the general theory.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Here it's not going to be an application of the theory over PIDs, because this ring is in fact a field

Comment: Which isn’t to say that it does not apply... just that it’s a little overly general ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Check that $ x^2+x+1 $ is irreducible in $ \mathbb F_2[x] $;
2. Prove that $ \mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2+x+1) $ is a field;
3. So what is a finitely-generated module over a field?

Comment: Whoops, I see! What if I'd used $x^2(x+1)$ as the polynomial instead?